# NOW() not updating datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table that looks like this:
Field: msg_sent_datetime
Type: datetime

yet when i use NOW() in a php mysql insert query it is staying as all zeros?

any idea why?

Comment: Just to be safe, it's probably a good idea to post some code.  It's likely that for whatever reason, you (or some library) is quoting the NOW() expression.

Comment: Post SQL query. If you are using some wrapper or abstraction class, put var_dump($sql) into the method you are using right before it calls a database to see what the SQL it sends to the database server looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using it only at the time of `INSERT`, you could make the field a `TIMESTAMP` and set a default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Without knowing more about the code it's difficult to suggest much else.

Example with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    msg TEXT,
    msg_sent_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Also, if you want it to always update when there's a change to the row, you can add the  `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property to the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    msg TEXT,
    msg_sent_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Of course, all of this is totally dependent on switching to `TIMESTAMP` which you may not want

Answer (score 0):

I dont knw exactly why, but mysql has 2 datetime functions: now() and sysdate(). Perhaps you can substitute now() with sysdate() to help you troubleshoot.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate